# How can I bind two text fields and filter with both in JS in a PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm a bit confused on how to explain better,lol.... Please help me out..

I have this

[image]

I filter with the filter text field...
for instance if i enter Excel 2016, it will display those two boxes with excel 2016 alone.
i just add that date field... my question is how can i merge both field in to filter the whole data....like filter field = Excel 2016 and then the date field = 01/12/21 then on final selection for date fied, it should should me the one only that contains the combination.

Below is the code i use for the filter field which is the only one working currently...

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

below is the html

```
      <div class="card-body" style="padding: 5px;">
        <!-- title -->
          <div class="d-md-flex align-items-center">
            <div>
              <h5 class="card-title">Filter Class Name</h5><hr>
                 <h5 class="card-subtitle"><!-- Search form -->
                   <form class="form-inline md-form form-sm">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Filter" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="Filter" aria-label="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   </form>
                 </h5>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

and below is the php query

```
<ul id="myUL" style=""> 
   <?php
       $query = "SELECT classname,cdate FROM `classnametb` ORDER BY classname";
       $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
       while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
         $classname = $r['classname'];
         $classdate = $r['cdate'];

         $classdate = date("m/d/y", strtotime($classdate));
      ?>
                             
       <li style="display: inline;"><a href="studentclass.php?course=<?php echo($classname); ?>&&cdate=<?php echo($classdate); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" style="width: 300px !important; margin-bottom: 5px;">
       <span class="btn-inner--text"><?php echo($classname.'('.$classdate.')'); ?>
       </span>
                                
   </a></li>
<?php } ?><hr>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML code as well?

Comment: okay @DamjanOstrelic i

Answer (score 0):

Both your inputs have the same id: `myInput`.

If you change the date input id to `date-input` for example,
then here is one option to build the filter using string literals:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input');
    date = dateInput.value.split("-");
    year = date[0];
    month = date[1];
    day = date[2];

    filter = `${input.value}(${month}/${day}/${year})`;

    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: when i used this, the query is not displaying anything